# Many to many relationship on same class not working

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a many to many relationship using EFCore on the same user class which I have based on EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUser following the instructions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772091/945721), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns#many-to-many) and [here](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration). I have the following user class:

```
public class MyApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<MyApplicationUserJunction> MyApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyApplicationUserJunction> ManagingMyApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my joining table:

```
public class MyApplicationUserJunction
{
    public int MyApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyApplicationUser MyApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public int ManagedMyApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyApplicationUser ManagedMyApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my OnModelConfiguring:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<MyApplicationUserJunction>()
        .HasKey(uj => new { uj.ManagedMyApplicationUserId, uj.MyApplicationUserId});

    builder.Entity<MyApplicationUserJunction>()
        .HasOne(uj => uj.MyApplicationUser)
        .WithMany(qu => qu.MyApplicationUsers)
        .HasForeignKey(uj => uj.MyApplicationUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<MyApplicationUserJunction>()
        .HasOne(uj => uj.ManagedMyApplicationUser)
        .WithMany(qu => qu.ManagingMyApplicationUsers)
        .HasForeignKey(uj => uj.ManagedMyApplicationUserId);
}
```

Whenever I run the EFCore tools add migrations command, I get the following error:

> The relationship from 'MyApplicationUserJunction.MyApplicationUser' to 'MyApplicationUser.MyApplicationUsers' with foreign key properties {'MyApplicationUserId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

I am using the EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet package 1.0.0-preview3-final.

I have tried only using a single navigation property on the User class, and I've tried not specifying the WithMany function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745465/ef-core-many-to-many-relationship-on-a-class/44574378#44574378) but with no success.

Comment: Read the docs for [IdentityUser.Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser.id(v=vs.111).aspx) and have a look at the type. The foreign key property has to be the same type

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at using int as the primary key in UserIdentity.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working? if yes please answer the question to share the knowledge.

Comment: Apologies @MohammedNoureldin I did get it working, I'll post an answer later today.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin answered, please let me know if I've missed anything, its been a while since I made those changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working with EF Core 1, following Sir Rufo's suggestion above I specified the type of the TKey:

```
public class MyApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<MyApplicationUserJunction> MyApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyApplicationUserJunction> ManagingMyApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and in the context:

```
public class MyApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<MyApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    ...
```

and in the AddIdentity section in ConfigureServices which also uses the generic IdentityRole:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(config =>
        {
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyApplicationContext, int>();
```

I then upgraded this to EF Core 2 which require some other alterations to get the Identity working. As described by pealmeid [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1364) you have to derive from the IdentityRole:

```
public class MyRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public MyRole() : base()
    {
    }

    public MyRole(string roleName)
    {
        Name = roleName;
    }
}
```

Used in ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<MyApplicationUser, MyRole>(config =>
            {
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyApplicationContext>();
            ...
```

I was also using cookie authentication before which is no longer configured in the AddIdentity config lambda but is instead done at the services level:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login");
        ...
```

Also a slight change to the DbContext signature to use the derived role type:

```
public class MyApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<MyApplicationUser, MyRole, int>
{
```

Comment: Thank you! actually that is what I was waiting to see, the second `ICollection` Property. I was not sure if that is the proper way.